# Python unittests almost never check types

Tags: java, python, unit-testing

I was going through a few tests written in Java using JUnit and I could'nt help noticing the emphasis which is laid on checking the "type" of objects. This is something I have never seen in Python test-suites.

Java being statically-typed and Python being dynamically-typed, should'nt the reverse be the case?

Comment: uhm, what? do you assume that list equals a tuple with the same content or what?

Comment: I haven't seen nor written much (if any) type checking code in Java unit tests. Not even quite sure what you actually mean. Could you post an example?

Comment: If you find yourself truly caring what type an object is (and not just that it provides the proper interface), you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In dynamically-typed languages, developers often follow the [duck typing principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) -- "if it looks like a duck and walks like a duck, it is a duck".  As long as the object does what all the tests require, does it really matter what kind of object it is?  Duck typing says no.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. +1!

Answer (score 5):

Python unit tests *do* check types. All the time. In fact, that's the *only* thing they are doing.

Python is duck-typed. Duck typing means that the type of an object is defined by its behavior. Unit tests test behavior. Ergo, they test types.

Comment: *"In fact, that's the* only *thing they are doing."* That's simply not true; they very often also test values. For example, if I were to test my `isqrt` function by `assertEqual(isqrt(9), 3)`, I'm not testing only that the return value is a number (or positive number, or whatever we want to call the return type), but rather a value.

Comment: @Mike Graham: Yes, you are testing that the behavior of your `isqrt` function is that it computes the square root. Which, in a duck-typed language, *is* its type.

Comment: That's not a useful definition of "type".

Answer (score 0):

in addition to seconding what everyone is saying about duck typing here, I'd also like to point you in the direction of the `types` module:

http://docs.python.org/library/types.html

... whose collection of types correspond to many builtins and other commonly used types, so that you may easily explicitly assert for whatever type you want, in your unit tests.